# How to disable character compositions in perl-mode?

Tags: perl, emacs, unicode

When I am in `perl` mode in emacs (recently upgraded to GNU Emacs 23.3.1), `::`, `->` and `=>` (and perhaps other symbol combinations) are reduced to `∷`, `→` and `⇒` symbols. This is playing havoc with my ability to copy and paste text, as well as cause readability bugs. Is there a way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: 23.3.1 or 24.3.1? (the latter being the current version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(setq perl-prettify-symbols nil)` should do it.  To tell you the truth, I can't figure out why/how it affects your ability to copy&paste text, since the replacement is only a visual "illusion".  I can understand the problem with readability, which is why I added the `perl-prettify-symbols` configuration.

Comment: By default, Emacs appears to replace character compositions with Unicode characters. If I copy and paste text from an Emacs session run within, say, Terminal.app, these Unicode characters are copied as-is, not as the original two characters.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Do not use the Copy & Paste Commands from Terminal.app, but those of Emacs itself, e.g. C-w.  This will copy the correct characters, not their visual representation.  If you indent to use the mouse for copy/paste, use a graphical Emacs session.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really going to work for most people, I suspect. I use both Terminal.app's copy and paste and Emacs' yank, depending on what's faster. This visual representation business is no good if it interferes with that, but at least it can be disabled!

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't think of the case where Emacs runs in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`M-x auto-composition-mode` should disable the auto-composition minor mode for the buffer, or `M-x global-auto-composition-mode` to do it globally.

If you want to turn it off forever you could add this to your .emacs:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(global-auto-composition-mode nil))
```

Comment: `global-auto-composition-mode` is a function, not a variable.  `(lambda () (global-auto-composition-mode -1))` is what's desired here (in emacs 26+ at least).